# Calculating horizontal and vertical components of force

Tags: forces, vectors

**4a) Calculate the horizontal component A and the vertical component B of:
i) a 6.0N force at 40 degrees to the vertical**

---

I'm not sure about this but would this be the way to calculate it?

$$6\sin(40) = 3.86  N$$

$$6\cos40 = 4.60 N$$

### Alright I think I understand this part now...

Additional Question about magnitude.....

**b) Calculate the magnitude and direction of the resultant of a 2.0N force acting due north and a 3.5N force acting due east.**

I know that the direction would be North-East as there is only two forces acting which are to North and to East.

Would magnitude be the hypotenuse? If yes would yoy be using pythagoras's theorem or trigonometry? If no then I have no clue how to do it?!

Any advice and information would be appreciated!

Comment: WHAT CAN I ******* DO TO GET AN ANSWER HERE? IS IT JUST TOO HARD TO ANSWER ONE A-LEVEL QUESTION!?

Comment: Hi Kristens Taurins. Welcome to Phys.SE. If you haven't already done so, please take a minute to read the definition of when to use the [homework-and-exercises](http://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/homework-and-exercises/info) tag, and the Phys.SE [policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714) for homework-like problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Draw a diagram.

As you understand Trigonometry, you know that $$Cos(\theta)=(\frac{Adj}{Hyp})$$

and

$$Sin(\theta)=(\frac{Opp}{Hyp})$$

for any right angled triangle.

In this case, your "Hypotenuse" is the $6.0N$, and your $\theta$ is what you have above.

This should help you confirm whether you are right or wrong in your attempt.

Comment: If this answer was satisfactory, you could mark it as such by clicking on the tick, which would help users with a similar problem in the future :)